# Getting Error " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." in ionic2

Tags: typescript, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to fetch data using WebApi which runs on *localhost:58682/home/index1* in Ionic2 app which runs on localhost:8100.
I am getting the following error message.

```html
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:58682/home/index1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My **service.ts** file

```html
 @Injectable()
export class ResponseService{
 
 private responseUrl='http://localhost:58682/home/index1';
   getresponseDetails()
    {
        return this.http.get(this.responseUrl).map(res=>res.json());
    }
    }
```

**ionic.config.json**

```html
{
  "name": "App",
  "app_id": "90594fdf",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "proxies":[
    {
      "path":"/home",
      "proxyUrl":"http://localhost:58682/home"
    }
  ]
}
```

I went through some CORS blogs but couldn't fix it. What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again using [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) in your browser.

It allows to you request any site with ajax from any source, no matter http/https discrepancies and the like. Practically adds the `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the response.

Please keep in mind that this is a band-aid solution. Your server response has to actually have the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` header, preferably with a more specific value than `*`.

Comment: Thanks but cannot i manually add it to my code rather than depending on the browser extension?

Comment: Please read my whole answer: Please keep in mind that this is a band-aid solution. Your server response has to actually have the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` header, preferably with a more specific value than `*`.

Comment: The actual server you are referencing needs to be edited to have this header in the responses it gives.

Comment: so i have to configure server side is it?..In my web api?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That or enable Https, or both.