# ASP .NET Core asynchronous partial view

Tags: drupal, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

From an ASP .NET Core web app I am trying to make a call to a Drupal web api using React.js, however I get the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '[my-drupal-api]' is therefore not allowed access.

I have tried adding the following to my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
   builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
   .AllowAnyMethod()
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   .AllowCredentials());
});

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

and I still get the same error.

I am curious if there is another way to do this server-side, without react. Is there way a way to do an asynchronous partial view that will load the data returned from the Drupal web api, without delaying the load of the rest of the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Startup can be configured like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public const string CorsPolicyName = "YourSiteCorsPolicyName";

    ...

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();

        services.AddCors(
            options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicyName, corsBuilder.Build());
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCors(CorsPolicyName);
    }
}
```

In your controllers you can mark with the defined constant:

```
[EnableCors( Startup.CorsPolicyName )]
public class YourController : Controller { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still get the same error: Failed to load http://1.1.1.1/api/news: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:11111' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Do you get this issue when the app is hosted on real server rather than on you local machine? You might be interested to read this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544425/getting-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-reques